# The include() function doesnt work?

Tags: php, required

I have a file **all.php** like this:

```
<?php
    $url=file('file.txt');
    foreach($url as $url1) {

      include($url1);

      sleep(60);
    }
?>
```

file.txt contain:

```
http://mywebsite.com/1.php
http://mywebsite.com/2.php
http://mywebsite.com/3.php
```

When I run **all.php**, it showed:
 PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '$url1' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

How to fix it ? Any recommend would be highly appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: Include is for code includes, this doesnt seem to be for that purpose. What you want to do with those urls?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        include ($line);
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

But you cannot use the file names like below:

```
http://mywebsite.com/1.php
http://mywebsite.com/1.php
http://mywebsite.com/1.php
```

as `allow_url_include` directive in php.ini is disabled on remote server due to security concern and It may be also disabled in your local PHP.ini configuration file. You can use the relative path of files like below:

```
1.php
../1.php
../..1.php
```

Comment: Hello, it show an error: PHP Warning:  include(http://mywebsite.com/1.php
): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
 in C:\mywebsite.com\call.php on line 7
[27-Nov-2014 23:58:15 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'http://mywebsite.com/1.php
' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\mywebsite.com\call.php on line 7

Comment: Hello, I enabled allow_url_include

Comment: This code worked:  include('http://mywebsite.com/1.php'); However , when I get URL from file, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, it showed same error: [28-Nov-2014 00:12:53 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  include(http://mywebsite.com/1.php
): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
 in C:\mywebsite.com\call.php on line 5
[28-Nov-2014 00:12:53 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'http://mywebsite.com/1.php
' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\mywebsite.com\call.php on line 5

Comment: You know how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Use   file_get_contents();

```
   <?php
       $url=file('file.txt');
       foreach($url as $url1) {

         echo $page_content = file_get_contents($url1);

         sleep(60);
       }
  ?>
```

Hope it will work as you need it.

Comment: Allow_url_open should be on in PHP.INI